# SQL Server display a column in whole number but also display numbers with decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SO for example: if i have a data like below

```
| Quantity |
|  10.000  |
|  4.000   |
|  10.000  |
| 17.500   |
```

then i want it to look like..

```
| Quantity |
|     10   |
|     4    |
|     10   |
|     17.5 |
```

**UPDATE:**
What i have tried so far:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(INT,T1.Quantity) [Qty]
FROM ORDR T0 
INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
```

Comment: What have you tried to do?  Post your query...

Comment: why do you want 1.0 to be displayed as 10 and 4.0 as 4. Your input and output expected in this question are not in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CONVERT function :

```
 SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT,17.500)
```

Comment: never thought of that.. Thank you Mansoor

Answer (score 0):

Use Cast or Convert to float instead of int.

```
      select cast([ColName]as float) from [tableName]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your REAL data type into INT, using CONVERT() function in your SELECT expression .
As I unterstood, your query consists consequence like as:

```
select [1] 

from [your_table]
```

Instead you need:

```
select Convert (int, [1]) 

from [your_table]
```